# Average and expected value in a biased coin toss

Tags: probability

Not sure on which SE site to ask this. It is essentially a math question however I am looking for a practical code solution.

I have a loop with an integer i which changes (according to a predefined set of rules) every time tails comes up in a biased coin toss. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume this number increments on every tails. The loop runs n times, or until heads comes up. If heads does not come up in n tosses, i = -n.

I am trying to find both the average value of i (not counting the case where i = -n), and the expected value.

Consider the following example C# code:

```
const int n = 10;      //loops n times
const double p = .25;  //probability of heads
int i = 1;             //variable number

Random rnd = new Random();

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    if (rnd.NextDouble() < p) break;
    i++;
}
if (i > n) i = -n;
```

To get the average value I figured I'd have to calculate a weighted average, with weight w=p^(j+1), and simply run the loop n times.

```
const int n = 10;      //loops n times
const double p = .25;  //probability of heads
int i = 1;             //variable number
double i_avg = 0.0;    //average
double total_w = 0.0;  //weight

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    double w = Math.Pow(p, j + 1.0);
    total_w += w;
    i_avg += i * w;
    i++;
}
i_avg /= total_w;
```

But this seems incorrect. On p = 0.25 and n = 10, the result is ~2.33. But in a simulation, I get an average value of ~3.40, and expected value of ~2.65.

What is the correct way to calculate these values? If possible, please include example code in a procedural programming language, as I find this easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

The probability of heads coming up on the first toss is p. 
On the second toss, we've already hit tails, which has a probability of 1-p, so the prob. of heads would be (1-p)*p. On the third it would be (1-p)*(1-p)*p = (1-p)^2*p, etc. So for every toss, the probability of heads coming up is

```
w = (1-p)^j*p
```

To get the expected value, add -n to the sum with probability (1-p)^n.

```
ev = (i_avg + (1-p)^n * (-n)) / (total_w + (1-p)^n)
```

And since total_w + (1-p)^n = 1,

```
ev =  i_avg + (1-total_w) * (-n)
```

So the final program would be:

```
const int n = 10;      //loops n times
const double p = .25;  //probability of heads
int i = 1;             //variable number
double i_avg = 0.0;    //average
double ev = 0.0;       //expected value
double total_w = 0.0;  //weight

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    double w = Math.Pow(1.0 - p, j) * p;
    total_w += w;
    i_avg += i * w;
    i++;
}
ev = i_avg + (1.0 - total_w) * (-n);
i_avg /= total_w;
```

I'd love to turn this into fancy Latex expressions but I have no idea how to do that.